# Почему появляется дополнительная скрытая колонка при добавлениии новой колонки в таблицу?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Недавно проводили миграцию пользовательской системы на Oracle 12c и последнию версию нашего продукта. Этот процесс заключался в запуске миграционных скриптов, которые в основном добавляли и изменяли таблицы. Мы заметили, что при добавлении в таблицу новой колонки со значением по умолчанию, появляется дополнительная скрытая колонка `SYS_NC00002$`.

Это можно воспроизвести так:

```sql
create table xxx (a integer);
alter table xxx add (b integer default 1);

select table_name, column_name, data_type, data_length, column_id,  
default_length, data_default from user_tab_cols where table_name='XXX';

Table_Name|column_Name |data_Type|data_Length|column_Id|default_Length|data_Default|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
XXX       |A           |NUMBER   |         22|        1|              |            |
XXX       |SYS_NC00002$|RAW      |        126|         |              |            |
XXX       |B           |NUMBER   |         22|        2|             1|1           |
```

Если посмотреть запросом значения этой скрытой колонки, то все они одинаковы:

```sql
select distinct SYS_NC00002$ from xxx;

Sys_Nc00002$|
-------------
01          |
```

Но что удивительно, если добавить сначало колонку и отдельным выражением определить значение по умолчанию, то никакой скрытой колонки не появится:

```sql
create table xxy (a integer);
alter table xxy add (b integer);
alter table xxy modify b default 1;

select table_name, column_name, data_type, data_length, column_id,  
default_length, data_default from user_tab_cols where table_name='XXY';

Table_Name|column_Name|data_Type|data_Length|column_Id|default_Length|data_Default|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
XXY       |A          |NUMBER   |         22|        1|              |            |
XXY       |B          |NUMBER   |         22|        2|             1|1           |
```

Может кто-то объяснить, для чего эта скрытая колонка? И почему она появляется только в первом примере, а во втором нет?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45756882

Answer (score 5):

В релизе 11g была введена новая техника оптимизации для повышения производительности DDL операций. Это нововведение позволяет экстремально снизить время выполнения, если добавить **NOT NULL** колонку со значением по-умолчанию к существующей таблице. В релизе 12c эта техника оптимизации была расширена так же и для **NULL** колонок имеющих значение по-умолчанию.

Посмотрим на примере таблицы с 1.000.000 строчек:

```sql
sql> create table xxy
as select rownum a from dual connect by level <= 1e6
;
```

Теперь добавим новую колонку и сравним 11g и 12c:

```sql
11g> alter table xxy add b number default 1;
--Table XXY altered. Elapsed: 00:01:00.998

12c> alter table xxy add b number default 1;
--Table XXY altered. Elapsed: 00:00:00.052
```

Обратите внимание на разницу во времени выполнения: 1M строчек изменены за 5 ms!

План выполнения показывает:

```sql
11g> select count(1) from xxy where b = 1;
  COUNT(1)
----------
   1000000
11g> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor);
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |       |       |  1040 (100)|          |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |      |     1 |    13 |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| XXY  |   898K|    11M|  1040   (1)| 00:00:13 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   2 - filter("B"=1)
Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)

12c> select count(1) from xxy where b = 1;
12c> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor);
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |       |       |   429 (100)|          |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |      |     1 |     5 |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| XXY  |  1000K|  4882K|   429   (2)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   2 - filter(DECODE(TO_CHAR(SYS_OP_VECBIT("SYS_NC00002$",0)),NULL,NVL("
              B",1),'0',NVL("B",1),'1',"B")=1)
Note
-----
   - statistics feedback used for this statement
```

План выполнения показывает для 12c в отличии от 11g довольно сложный предикат, который использует новую скрытую колонку `SYS_NC00006$`. Этот предикат даёт понять, что БД внутри себя считает, что колонка `B` потенциально может содержать значения отличающиеся от таковых по-умолчанию. Из этого следует, БД в действительности не производит сразу изменение всех строк, чтобы добавить значение по-умолчанию для новой колонки.

Для чего всё таки колонка `SYS_NC00006$` создаётся?

```sql
12c> select column_name, virtual_column, hidden_column, user_generated 
from user_tab_cols
where table_name = 'XXY'
;
COLUMN_NAME      VIR HID USE
---------------- --- --- ---
B                NO  NO  YES
SYS_NC00002$     NO  YES NO 
A                NO  NO  YES

12c> select a, b, SYS_NC00002$ hid from xxy where a in (1,10);

         A          B HID            
---------- ---------- ----------------
         1          1                 
        10          1                 

12c> update xxy set b=1 where a=10 and b=1;
1 row updated.

12c> select a, b, SYS_NC00002$ hid from xxy where a in (1,10);
         A          B HID            
---------- ---------- ----------------
         1          1                 
        10          1 01
```

Обратите внимание на разницу в значениях колонки `B` и им соответствующих значениях скрытой колонки `SYS_NC00006$`. БД просто проверяет на основании значения скрытой внутренней колонки и с помощью функции `SYS_OP_VECBIT`, надо ли применять для колонки `B` значение по-умолчанию, или колонка уже содержит реальное значение добавленное явным путём.

Почему скрытая колонка не создаётся в случае двух раздельных DDL выражений?

```sql
12c> alter table xxy add (b integer);
12c> alter table xxy modify b default 1;

12c> select count(b), count(coalesce(b,0)) nulls  from xxy where b = 1 or b is null;

  COUNT(B)      NULLS
---------- ----------
         0    1000000
```

В этом случае, значение новой колонки останется `NULL` для всех строчек. Так как никакого обновления в действительности не требуется, то и в оптимизации нет никакой необходимости.

[Статья на OTN](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/database/ddl-optimizaton-in-odb12c-2331068.html), использованая как источник, была удалена или временно недостуна. В настоящее время доступен только её [перевод на китайский](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/cn/articles/database/ddl-optimizaton-in-odb12c-2331068-zhs.html).

Comment: отличный ответ! Можете ссылку на OTN подправить?

Comment: Спасибо! Ссылка по видимому "протухла" (в оригинальном ответе тоже). Попробую заново найти, но если действительно статью удалили, а не переместили, придётся убрать ссылку вообще.